# Set selected option in angular js based on ordinal position of item

Tags: angularjs

I am loading a select control in angular js from an array of json objects.
I want to set the selected property if the ordinal position of an item in the collection matches some value (such as 3 for example), eg,

```
<option ng-repeat="query in ReportQueries" selected="query.ordinal==3" 
value="query.ReportQueryID">{{query.QueryName}}</option>
```

There is no property "ordinal" on my object, I am hoping there is some index or counter angular generates and exposes when iterating through a collection.

Does anyone know if this is possible?  Thanks

Thanks

Comment: Where is your json object?

Comment: Json object is simple array like this $scope.ReportQueries = [{ReportQueryID: 123, QueryName: 'blah'}, {ReportQueryID: 124, QueryName: 'test'} ];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an Example which may help you: **Updated**

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.test = 3;

    $scope.ReportQueries = [{
      ReportQueryID: 1,
      QueryName: 'Amy'
    }, {
      ReportQueryID: 2,
      QueryName: 'Ben'
    }, {
      ReportQueryID: 3,
      QueryName: 'Betty'
    }, {
      ReportQueryID: 4,
      QueryName: 'Hannah'
    }, {
      ReportQueryID: 5,
      QueryName: 'John'
    }]
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <select ng-model="test">
    <option ng-repeat="query in ReportQueries" ng-selected="test==$index">{{query.QueryName}}</option>
  </select>
  <h1>Selected Index is: {{test}}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure this addresses my issue.  I need to set the 3rd item (or 4th or 1st, depends on the value of another variable) in the collection as selected when the select is loaded.  This isn't based on the id of the item its based on its position in the list.  The ids may not be sequential or in order.

Comment: Pease explain what you exactly need in an example.

Comment: When angular loads my list of options, I want it to set the selected item based on ordinal position of the item, not the id or any other property of the item.  I have a variable (in the example above, $scope.test) which is the ordinal position of the item I want to be selected, in this case, the third item.  Not item with id=3, but the third item in the list.  What I need is the same as doing 
    $('#selectid')[0].selectedIndex = 3;

Comment: check the Update

Comment: $index, sweet, I knew it had to be something like that.  Your a champ!